# Prevent image upload to AWS in development/test in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have inherited a project that uses Paperclip for image processing, which also uploads to a AWS bucket, normally I use Carrierwave and choose to save files locally when in Test or Development environments

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
 else
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :region => 'eu-west-1'
   }

    config.fog_directory =  ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
    config.fog_public     = true
    config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
 end
end
```

How can I achieve the same thing with paperclip? I have read that you can [Define Defaults](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#defaults)  in a initializer file.

But I am a bit unsure on what options to pass.

Comment: The title is really confusing, are you trying to stop the images from uploading to AWS?

Comment: @Mike apologies, for clarification i have changed the title, what i am trying to achieve is to save images locally when in test/dev and when in production then use my S3 bucket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an initializer like this

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test? 
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = 'filesystem'
else
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = 's3'
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] = {
    bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
  # other config...
end
```

For more options about S3, see also http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3

Just add those options to the `Paperclip::Attachment.default_options` hash :)

Comment: Thanks, much prefer to put the paperclip config into an initializer as opposed to in the model class

Comment: i get an error `Paperclip::Errors::StorageMethodNotFound: Cannot load storage module ':filesystem'`

Comment: ah dont worry. think it's `filesystem`

Comment: just to update i found that we need to pass 'filesystem' and 's3' for this to work, thanks again for your help

Comment: Actually `filesystem` is the default place to store attachments. I usually omit it

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip can have different storage for each field, so look for how s3 storage is selected.
Probably it's `has_attached_file :foo, storage: :s3, ...`, to save locally storage should be `:filesystem`